# Ubuntu 14.04 - autofs and bind mount

Tags: 14.04, automount, bind

is it possible to tell autofs to use "mount --rbind..." instead of "mount --bind..." by default?

The reason is that we are exporting a folder, let's call that /exports, which holds different other mounts. E.g. /exports/sda2, /exports/sdb1, /exports/sdc1.

Everything works great if a remote client mounts /exports due to the crossmnt option in /etc/exports.
On the local machine, where the export is done, autofs detects it as local and does a bind mount but unfortunately not rbind which leads to that the newly created bind-mounted folder does not show the filesystems underneath /exports, but just the folders from the underlaying filesystem.

We wanted to avoid using the symlink option and we already tried to set "-O rbind" as an automount option which was passed to the automount call of nfs, but was dropped when the bind mount call happens.

Maybe there is another approach to this problem? If not, I think we will use the symlink.

EDIT: Just realized that using a local NFS mount with async as export option should also work.

Thanks
Thomas